# Python Networking responding wtih 'b'

Tags: python

I've just started python networking, and after looking at a few internet tutorials, I gave it a go... only problem is, whenever I get a response from the sever, it prints as in:

Recieved from: (Host & Port)b'Hey' - where I haven't put the b anywhere.

Here is the server code:

```
import socket
import tkinter
import time
import sys

def Main():
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.configure(background='black')
host = '10.0.0.2'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(1)
c, addr = s.accept()
while True:
    con = tkinter.Label(top, text="Connection from: " + str(addr), bg='red', fg='white').pack()
    data = c.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn = tkinter.Label(top, text="Recieved from: " + str(addr) + str(data), bg='black', fg='white').pack()
    top.mainloop()
c.close() 
Main()
```

And my client:

```
import socket

def Main():
host = '10.0.0.2'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))

message = input("> ")
while message != 'quit':
    s.send(message.encode('ascii'))
    message = input(">")

s.close()
Main()
```

Thanks for any input - I'm not really good at this yet! (My hosts aren't my computer so that's not the issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [socket.recv() in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) it returns a bytes object, not a normal string. You can convert it to a normal string as follows:

data.decode('utf-8')